# Is this translation correct?

Tags: translation-check

"Hasn't your mother told you she doesn't like your girlfriend?
"Materne(nonne mater)non tua tibi dixit illam non amare amicam tuam?"
I find this weird because I learned that a double negative in Latin makes an affirmative. Especially because it's a question with a negative meaning. I don't know if I'm being clear about my doubt.
Can we construct sentences like this in Latin?

Comment: Is your question specifically about the two *non*s? I would recommend replacing the first one with a _nonne_ at which point you don't have a double negative at all, but if your question is about the double negative rather than this specific sentence, that won't be very helpful to you.

Comment: It's about the two "nons". So, I just replace the "nonne", right?

Answer (score 8):

'Say that *x* is not the case' is routinely rendered by using a form of *negare* as the main verb with a positive infinitive in the indirect statement.

Also, if, as seems likely, the mother is the subject of both 'told' and 'like'), you need to use the reflexive pronoun *se*, not *illam*, as the accusative subject of the infinitive in the indirect statement.

*nonne mater negavit se amicam tuam diligere?*